# (MacOS) EDIT: Bulk copy/export name, Modification & Creation Date from multiple files in a folder

Tags: macos, script, automation, file, text

Mac OS 12 Monterey: I have a bunch of files inside a folder that I want to get the Date Modified and Created from and copy it into a text document or some kind of tab delimited document. I have no idea how to do this.

Opening each one and manually copy/pasting the Creation Date is not an option, as this is hundreds of files.

Can this operation be automated or scripted?

EDIT: I found that using the following will give me all the various date formats and puts them in a txt file, and all dates preserved:

```
(stat -f "%N%tAccess:%t%Sa%tModify:%t%Sm%tChange:%t%Sc%tBirth:%t%SB" *)>creation.txt
```

However, when I then try to copy that information into an excel sheet, even though it keeps the days and times, all the years are changed to 2023.

txt file:

> EXAMPLE.mp3   Access: Dec  9 11:48:21
> 2023  Modify: May 19 21:37:55 2020    Change: Dec  7 19:03:24
> 2023  Birth:  Nov 26 06:07:58 2014

Pasted into excel spreadsheet:

> EXAMPLE.mp3   Access: Saturday,
> December 9, 2023  Modify: Friday, May 19, 2023    Change: Thursday,
> December 7, 2023  Birth:  Sunday, November 26, 2023

Comment: Could you take one sample file and show its full date with `ls -l file.whatever` and then hand edit the results to show us the date format you need? This will be fairly straightforward with tools like `awk` and `ls` - edit these in the question if possible so everyone can see the request in the body and not the comments

Answer (score 0):

You could use the command given below. The results would be written to the file `creation.txt`.

```bash
(cd path;stat -f "%N%t%SB" *)>creation.txt
```

You should replace `path` with the path to the folder (including folder name) where the files are stored. For example, if the files are in a folder named `My Files`, which is in your `Documents` folder, then enter the following.

```bash
cd ~/Documents
(cd "My Files";stat -f "%N%t%SB" *)>creation.txt
```

The file `creation.txt` will be written to your `Documents` folder. To see the contents, enter the following command.

```bash
cat creation.txt
```

Example output is given below.

```bash
UserManual.pdf  Jan 12 08:02:21 2021
bye.txt Dec  3 21:19:35 2023
hi.txt  Dec  3 21:19:24 2023
something.bin   Dec  3 21:20:02 2023
```